# Sending Email using Sql server 2012 in single mail

Tags: sql-server, sendmail

I am trying to send mail using Stored Procedure in Sql server 2012.

The can send the mail using code which i have written.

**Output i am getting**

For Example, If i have 5 rows in my table then each row is taken as one mail.
And i am getting 5 mails for 5 different records.

**example**

**Mail 1**

EmpName: Abc

EmpId  : 123

**Mail 2**

EmpName: xyz

EmpId  : 456

**Mail 3**

EmpName: def

EmpId  : 789

etc

**Actual requirement**

I want all the 5 rows to be sent in a single mail.

**example**

**Mail 1**

EmpName: Abc

EmpId  : 123

EmpName: xyz

EmpId  : 456

EmpName: def

EmpId  : 789

etc

Here is the Stored Procedure i have written :

```
DECLARE 
@out_desc VARCHAR(1000),
@out_mesg VARCHAR(10)

DECLARE @EmpName VARCHAR(20),
@LoginDate datetime,
@EmailId NVARCHAR(max),
@EmpID NVARCHAR(50),
@Salary NVARCHAR(50),
@MonthName NVARCHAR(50)

DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @subject NVARCHAR(500)

DECLARE C1 CURSOR READ_ONLY
FOR

select EmpName,EmpID,SUM(SalaryToBePaid) as Salary,
(select EmailId from EmailIds) as EmailId,
( SELECT DATENAME(MM, GETDATE())) as MonthName 
from EmployeeSalary
where 
LoginDate between DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -3) and GETDATE()     
Group By
EmpName,EmpID

OPEN C1
FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO 
@EmpName,@EmpID,@Salary,@EmailId,@MonthName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @body = '<b><U>Employees :</U></b><br />'  +
     '<br/><b>Employee Name     :   '  + @EmpName + 
     '<br/><b>Employee Id       :     '  + @EmpID +  
   + '<br/><b>Salary : '  + @Salary     
   SET @subject = @MonthName  + '    Month Salary Details'                  
    EXEC sp_send_mail --sp_send_mail 
    'xxx@mail.com', --- add your Email Address here
    'password',       ----add your Password here

    @EmailId,
    @subject,        
    @body,
    'htmlbody', @output_mesg = @out_mesg output, @output_desc = @out_desc    output

    PRINT @out_mesg
    PRINT @out_desc

FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO 
@EmpName, @EmpID, @Salary,@EmailId,@MonthName
END

CLOSE C1
DEALLOCATE C1
```

Please help me..

Comment: `sp_send_mail`  or `sp_send_dbmail` aren't meant for generating and sending reports. That's the job of Reporting Services. They are meant to send alerts to administrators. Formatting, recipient management, scheduling are all but impossible for anything more. You are using the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

REMOVE THE CURSOR. SIMPLY USE THE SELECT RATHER CURSOR. THAT WILL GIVE YOU GOOD RESULT.

BELOW IS AN EXAMPLE, REPLACE WITH YOUR OWN

```
DECLARE @bodyMsg nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @subject nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @tableHTML nvarchar(max)

SET @subject = 'Query Results in HTML with CSS'


SET @tableHTML = N'<table id="box-table" >' +
N'<tr><font color="Green"><th>SpecialOfferID</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Category</th>
<th>StartDate</th>
<th>EndDate</th>
</tr>' +
CAST ( ( 

SELECT td = CAST([SpecialOfferID] AS VARCHAR(100)),'',
td = [Description],'',
td = [Type],'',
td = [Category] ,'',
td = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),[StartDate],120) ,'',
td = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),[EndDate],120) 
FROM [AdventureWorks].[Sales].[SpecialOffer]    
ORDER BY [SpecialOfferID]
FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
N'</table>'
```

Comment: I tried your code , i am getting error . its saying   "Error
At least one recipient is required, but none were found".